# Password guessing with Brute force attack

Tags: passwords, brute-force

> When key guessing, the key length used in the cipher determines the practical feasibility of performing a brute-force attack, with longer keys exponentially more difficult to crack than shorter ones. A cipher with a key length of N bits can be broken in a worst-case time proportional to 2^N and an average time of half that. Average combination will be 2^N-1.

Why is the formula 2^N consist of a 2?

Answer (score 2):

The key length is measured in bits as a binary value. This is either a 0 or a 1, so there's 2 different possible answers for each position.

A key length of 1 can be either 0 or 1. Two possible combinations. This can be represented as 2^1.

A key length of 2bits can be 00, 01, 10, 11. Four possible combinations, or 2^2.

The 2 will be constant, it's the number of bits that will change.

Comment: Alright thanks alot! I'm just curious why is it measured in binary form instead of random character password? Is it because cipher is assumed to be binary?

Comment: Key strength/length is usually measured in bits, as most encryption routines operate at the binary level, not the character one. Key combinations can be measured if you know the key range used, for instance an 8 character password using only lowercase ASCII letters would have 26^8 different combinations. In reality though that password you type in is usually transformed into a hash, which manipulates that again at the binary level.